# When chaining method calls in JavaScript, in what order are functions called?

Tags: javascript, chaining, method-chaining

Let's say I'd have this chain of calls:

```
var btn = $('#mybtn');
btn.addClass('is-active').text(btn.attr('data-alt-active'));
```

It's obvious that `addClass` is going to be called before `text` but when is `btn.attr` called? Just before `text` is called or before the entire chain?

Answer (score 0):

Running this:

`<span id="mybtn" data-alt-active="Alternative text">Hello</span>`

```
function aliasWrap(func, msg) {
    function _wrapped() {
        console.log(msg);
        return func.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return _wrapped
}

$.fn._addClass = aliasWrap($.fn.addClass, 'addClass called');
$.fn._text = aliasWrap($.fn.text, 'text called');
$.fn._attr = aliasWrap($.fn.attr, 'attr called');

var o = $('#mybtn');

o._addClass('is-active')._text(o._attr('data-alt-active'));
```

Outputs the following in console:

```
addClass called
attr called
text called
```

tl;dr; The function called inside the chained method call will be called just before the chained method is called.